# Construction of optimal ensemble to show quantum steerability

Tags: entanglement, nonclassicality, steering

In [Wiseman et al. (2007)](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0612147), in the process of deriving necessary and sufficient conditions for the steerability of some classes of states, the authors show (lemma 1, page 3) how to construct an *optimal ensemble* $F^\star=\{\rho_\xi^\star\mathscr P_\xi^\star\}$ such that, if this ensemble *cannot* explain Bob's state via a local hidden state, then no other ensemble can.

---

More precisely, the context is that of Alice trying to convince Bob that she can *steer* his state by means of her performing measurements on her part of the system. In other words, we assume that Alice and Bob share some state $W$, and that Alice performs measurements $A\in\mathscr M$ ($\mathscr M$ denoting here the measurements that Alice can choose to perform) on her part of the system.
If Alice performs measurement $A$ and gets result $a$, then Bob's state becomes
$$\tilde\rho_a^A=\operatorname{Tr}_\alpha[W(\Pi_a^A\otimes I)],$$
where $\operatorname{Tr}_\alpha$ denotes the partial trace with respect to Alice's part of the system, and the tilde is used to remember that this is an *unnormalised* state.

If Bob *can* describe this state by means of some prior *local hidden state* $\rho=\sum_\xi p_\xi\rho_\xi$ as
$$\tilde\rho_a^A=\sum_\xi\mathscr P(a|A,\xi)p_\xi\rho_\xi,\tag5$$
then he is *not* convinced that Alice can steer his system, as it would mean that he can describe his observations by simply assuming that what he is measuring is some local state $\rho$ that is not affected by Alice.

---

**My question is about the aforementioned lemma that is proved in the paper: *why is the ensemble $F^\star$ optimal*?**

The lemma is as follows:

> Consider a group $G$ with unitary representation $U_{\alpha\beta}(g)=U_\alpha(g)\otimes U_\beta(g)$. Suppose that for every measurement $A\in\mathscr M$, outcome (that is, eigenvalue) $a\in\lambda(A)$, and group element $g\in G$, we have $U_\alpha^\dagger(g)A U_\alpha(g)\in\mathscr M$, and moreover
>   $$\tilde\rho_a^{U_\alpha^\dagger(g)AU_\alpha(g)}=U_\beta(g)\tilde\rho_a^A U^\dagger_\beta(g).$$
>   Then there exists a $G$-covariant optimal ensemble, that is, one such that $\forall g\in G$
>   $$\{\rho_\xi^\star\mathscr P_\xi^\star\}=\{U_\beta(g)\rho_\xi^\star U_\beta^\dagger(g)\mathscr P_\xi^\star\}.$$

They then proceed to give an ensemble that they prove (not that I understand this proof, but that is another matter) *does* satisfy **(5)**.
Why is this then proving that if this ensemble *does not* satisfy **(5)** then no other ensemble can? I find this quite confusing, given that we just proved that it *does* satisfy **(5)**.